# Canonical question for R gotcha: colon operator takes higher precedence than arithmetic

Tags: discussion, canonical

It is a frequent R gotcha that `1:10+5` does not do what you expect it do. All of us R programmers have been bitten by it, usually several times.

Surprisingly, although it comes up a lot, we don't seem to have any canonical questions, or even any well-titled questions. Which should we use, and what title should it have?

- [R script : difference btw df[,1:3] vs df [,i:i+2] , i=1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33658316/r-script-difference-btw-df-13-vs-df-ii2-i-1/33658434)
- [Brackets make a vector different. How exactly is vector expression evaluated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32181742/brackets-make-a-vector-different-how-exactly-is-vector-expression-evaluated/32182445)
- [subscripting not working in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32016539/subscripting-not-working-in-r/32016701#32016701)
- [for-loop inconsistencies in R on i+1:5 expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31564651/for-loop-inconsistencies-in-r)
- [Subsetting R with dynamic variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38335734/subsetting-r-with-dynamic-variables)
- [correlation loop keep getting NA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27327146/correlation-loop-keep-getting-na)
- [Why does the vector gets expanded in the loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24981048/why-does-the-vector-gets-expanded-in-the-loop/24981144)
- [Subsetting a vector with variables changes the length of the result vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23871191/subsetting-a-vector-with-variables-changes-the-length-of-the-result-vector)
- there's nothing useful under [[r] precedence colon](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5br%5d%20precedence%20colon)
- yet another duplicate today [Binning by Median](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/15503/binning-by-median/15508)
  over at DataScience.SE
- and it wasn't even mentioned in [What's the biggest R-gotcha you've run across? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535021/whats-the-biggest-r-gotcha-youve-run-across)
- [Trying to figure out For Loops](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52193234)

Comment: Once you find one, Send a PR to [HammeR](https://github.com/r-public/HammeR). Thanks :)

Comment: I wish more language designers had the courage to just make mixing infix operators from different families an error.  It's so little extra effort to write either `1:(10+5)` or `(1:10)+5` and remove the ambiguity.

Comment: Additionally, a canonical answer ought to contrast the behavior with that of MATLAB, where `1:i+10` behaves as `1:(i+10)`.

Comment: @BenVoigt: probably that should be a separate question, e.g. *"What are language gotchas between R and MATLAB?"*

Comment: @smci oh no, that would be far too broad.  It's entirely appropriate for an answer about precedence to note that it is different in some other languages and list a couple examples.  Missing one would not make such an answer wrong, the way missing a gotcha would in your suggestion (which is why questions of the type you proposed are explicitly offtopic)

Comment: This seems to be more suitable for the Documentation area than as a question and answer.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg: no, it's also on-topic here: we need a canonical question. There are already too many historical duplicates. I want to know why their titles all suck, so I can write a canonical one with a good title.

Comment: Obviously there are differing opinions on that.

Comment: How about "Why doesn't the sequence `1:n + k` run like 1, 2, ..., n + k?" Anyway, when you've posted your canonical Q&A, you can/should post an answer on this meta so we can find it. Personally, I think it makes more sense in Q&A than Docs.

Comment: @Frank: usually users don't isolate that it's the `:` operator behaving differently to what they would visually expect, or what's standard in other languages. I'd call it *"Why did an expression with m:n not behave as expected?"*

Comment: But that doesn't have a `+` or `-` in it, right? `m:n` behaves the same in MATLAB and R. Anyway, I guess another idea would be: if you think there might be multiple ways to approach this Q&A, you can post them as answers below and solicit votes and other feedback to help you decide.

Comment: Yeah, sure, something like *"Why did an expression with m:n+k not behave as expected?"*

Comment: Do we really need a Q/A for a RTFM question ? Handling operator precedence sounds blatantly RTFM for me.

Comment: And preaching for myself (feel free to turn it CW if you feel it's needed): [this one explain it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31564651/for-loop-inconsistencies-in-r)

Comment: And re "even any well-titled questions": there will never be, as no one think about operator precedence when asking about a strange behavior when using ranges, so obvisouly the questions will never speak about `:` or operator precedence.

Comment: @Tensibai: it's not an "RTFM question"; existing users of Python numpy/pandas, MATLAB/Octave or other matrix or statistical languages will all already have a (legitimate) implicit expectation of how the operator should work, coming from their language. We wouldn't expect them to look up the help page on '+' or '*' before using them. That's why this is a language-design gotcha, not an RTFM.

Comment: Well, I disagree there, when something doesn't behave as expected the first action should be to create a mcve and then read the doc of what is involved to see if there's something in the doc saying it works differently than expected. When changing language, expecting the same behavior is indeed legitimate, but when the code show you something unexpected, going to read the doc  is a good ha it IMHO

Comment: @Tensibai: you're assuming that it's self-evident where in a line or several lines of code things are acting weird - with this specific issue it's not. That's why it's called a gotcha. As someone who's debugged it in both R and Matlab/Octave, I can confirm it's not. Also, look at the frequency with which other (sometimes, experienced) users encounter it - that's why we have ten such links above. Last, complicating factor is that operators like `:` are punctuation and thus totally Google-/SO-proof (SymbolHound's coverage sucks). R learners would not search for `seq`, nor the syntax `help(':')`

Comment: That's why I just talked about creating a mcve, but well, let's agree to disagree as obviously a fair bunch of people doesn't do it and I'm still baffled by the amount of upvotes my answers mostly quoting the doc can get across the network.

Comment: @Tensibai: for this specific issue, we would need not one but multiple MCVEs (list/matrix slicing, for-loop, other use-cases), but even after creating them, none of them would be findable via any of SO search, SO tags, SO keywords, Google, SymbolHound etc., so the question would still get reasked regularly, and we would still have the manual close overhead. So yeah I/we should definitely try to create/curate MCVEs, but that is only half the battle  on this one. Increasing awareness of all the possible manifestations and doing the constant manual closing overhead is the other.

Comment: My point is the opposite, I mean that's what people should do before asking. I stand by the point it doesn't happen and even writing a canonical question won't help because as people don't search the root cause of their problem they won't search about operator precedence, so we'll still have dupes of this kind anyway. I doubt a question on SO will increase awareness of this

Comment: @Tensibai: indeed, but *"let us not let the perfect be the enemy of the good"*. We can't prevent new users joining SO and behaving badly initially. But perhaps we can guide the subset of them amenable to learning. Guiding them towards writing MCVEs is clearly getting lots of attention right now. But even if a question contains an MCVE, it may still be totally resistant to search.

Answer (score -1):

My suggestion: ask a question about it with whatever title you think is best. Then supply a community wiki answer and accept it.

Comment: Among other things, I'm asking you all what title is best?

Comment: Why do you believe such a question/answer pair is needed? This issue is clearly explained in "An Introduction to R" (section 2.3), which everyone who uses R should have read or suffer the consequences. Operator precedence is also detailed in `help("Syntax")`.

Comment: @Roland I don't really, but SO has decision-making procedures (ie voting) that - better than a meta convo - can decide whether something is worth being a question and procedures (ie editing) that can decide what that question should be titled.

Comment: @Roland, that's exactly the attitude among R users that the language can arbitrarily change operator semantics or keywords from what is standard in other languages, and as long as it's buried somewhere in the documentation (or a third-party guide like R-inferno), that we can't be more helpful to users. Gotchas should be documented (R differs from Matlab, Python/pandas, and others), and in this case a canonical question is needed, with a generic title, and to merge all the exact duplicates I listed into it. To prevent wasting time. (Have you never encountered a gotcha in another language?)

Comment: You are entitled to your opinion. I do not agree that official documentation needs to be replicated on SO. If you make assumptions instead of checking documentation you deserve what you get.

Comment: @Roland: I never said "official documentation needs to be replicated on SO", you're misrepresenting me. I did say "major gotchas, esp. where R differs arbitrarily from standard or expected behavior in other similar languages, deserve to get a canonical question"*. I don't make assumptions, I read documentation. This still doesn't excuse arbitrarily differing from standard semantics without calling users' attention to it prominently (list the gotchas). In the case of `m:n+k`, it's not like raising `:` precedence over arithmetic buys us any special functionality, it just causes confusion.

Comment: @smci I do not agree with your premise that there is a need to adhere to standard semantics or even that there is such a standard. To my maths sensibilities it makes perfect sense that `+` got the lowest precedence.