# Tag alias 'tab' → 'tabs' is not what you think it is: "multiple UI elements", not "\t character"

Tags: discussion, tag-disambiguation

[tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tab) is aliased to [tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tabs), which has 11.7K questions. However its definition is nothing to do with the ASCII character \t or 007, but *"user interface pattern that allows for the display of multiple pages or elements"*. Hence around ~10% of those questions are mistagged.

So should we:

- unalias 'tab'
- and/or create a new tag 'tab-character' to avoid bad autosuggests on the word "tab"?
- or just retag those questions 'whitespace'? (probably a bad idea)
- and then delete 'tab'

Comment: There could also be ambiguity between the tab _key_ and the tab _character_, e.g. user events vs. I/O and formatting.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: Uhuh. I didn't see questions related to the Tab key, but "tab key" finds [~5K questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22tab+key%22). Most are untagged, some tagged 'whitespace'

Comment: Did you try ["tab button"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22tab+button%22)? I see a few even on the first page tagged [tag:tabs].

Comment: Aargh. I thought this one would be simple...

Comment: Did you say 007?

Comment: We're facing a [tab] explosion.

Comment: Do we really need a tag for the tab character ..? Then we'd need a tag for the "A" character as well, etc.

Comment: @Teemu: no it's obviously not as trivial and pointless as a tag for the 'A' character. I'm still not saying we do need, just asking. Taking a brief look at tab character", there seem to be subcategories on regexes, indentation, printing whitespace, parsing input, editors...some of those seem to merit it and some don't. Take a look for yourself.

Comment: Umh ... It's possible to write about 30k of text to the question, the entire question should not be included in tags. Questions might be good, but they really don't need "tab-character" tag, or "enter-character" or ö-character.

Comment: @Teemu note that we do have [tag:enter], a tag about the enter/return key, with 688 questions (not saying we need it, though)

Comment: Note that we have a [newline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/newline) tag, a [carriage return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/carriage_return) tag, a [backslash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/backslash) tag...

Comment: So many tags to burnitate ... Who's the backslash expert of the community?

Comment: @Teemu apparently one who can resolve [tag:tab]-vs-[tag:space] dispute

Comment: A [colon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/colon) tag... impressively useless ;)

Comment: @gnat Wasn't that resolved in the annual survey a couple of years ago? Or was it a tie?

Comment: @Teemu My ninja/samurai skills do make me an expert in slashing people's backs, so...

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Well, you've to somehow inject yourself to the [top users](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/backslash/topusers) of the tag then ..?

Comment: Not so fast with assumptions, though. Some of those can be useful, others are junk. [backslash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/backslash) for escaping. I once had to thunk out to the shell from inside another scripting language to call perl, so some of the command line had to be quadruply \\\\-escaped, and internal quotes on it had to be doubly-escaped.

Comment: : (colon) is an important operator in most vector languages (R,Matlab/Octave), yet there's a [well-known gotcha in operator precedence](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338980/canonical-question-for-r-gotcha-colon-operator-takes-higher-precedence-than-ari), such that `1:10+5` means `1:15` in Matlab/Octave and Python indexing, yet `6:15` in R

Comment: Again, Then we would need [<], [>], [=], [==], [!=] ... the list is endless. Tags are for classifying the question, they don't need to contains the question itself.

Comment: @Teemu: you're not listening to me. Of course we don't need those tags. And as you well know they're already contained in [comparison-operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/comparison-operators).  I said there may be a weak case for a tag for colon operator, because it's a) not already covered and b) important. Also c) in R it can also be written as `seq(...)`, and that is not "containing the question". Again, not so fast with your assumptions.

Comment: My assumptions are not too "fast", just that I don't agree with you doesn't mean I wouldn't have thought the things through. Just as an example, we've various types of [operator*] tags, I can't see any reason, why questions about colon operator can't fit in any of these existing categories? Classifying doesn't mean that you could point to a very specific single subject with a tag. Categories (or "classes") should be more wider in order to be useful when searching.

Comment: @Teemu: there's no point in intentionally misstating that there is no [comparison-operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/comparison-operators) in order to mock the comment. And even if there wasn't, noone would suggest creating individual '<'/'>'/'=='/'<='/'>='/'<=>' rather than one 'comparison-operators'. As to colon-operator being distinct to 'operator' in general, that's because it pops up in sequences, indexing, slicing, sometimes with negative or variable stride, sometimes for very long (or infinite) sequence lengths. So it's a binary/ternary operator with very different...

Comment: ...behavior than simply a two-way/n-way comparison operator returning a boolean (or NA)

Comment: ?? I didn't say, that "there is no comparison-operators tag", I said, that we've various operators tags [including comparison-operator].

Comment: _something something_ [tab]ula rasa?